# Remove the recent apps part on Xiaomi Mi A2

Tags: xiaomi, recents-screen

I am using Android 10 on Xiaomi Mi A2 and want to remove the "recent apps" part from my menu, but there aren't the options shown above.

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

"Recent apps" is a standard part of Android navigation and it cannot be removed. You should probably just stop swiping up that long from the bottom and you will never encounter the recent apps screen.